# Description Logics; mandatory participation

Tags: owl, description-logic

I have a UML conceptual diagram; and I want to express it as DL ontology. UML classes are captured as DL concepts, where associations are captured by means of roles. One important perspective is multiplicities among UML classes. A to-one multiplicity (0..* - 0..1) is captured by a functional object property, and to make the one (0..1) side mandatory, i.e. (0..* - 1) references talk about mandatory participation implying a maximum and minimum multiplicity of 1 on the to-one side.

Here is the [reference](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~lembo/AAAI-10-tutorial-DL4DataAccess/DL-Lite-Notes.pdf)

[image]

An association A between classes C1 and C2 is formalized in DL by means of a
role A on which we enforce the assertions

[image]

To express the multiplicity ml..mu on the participation of instances of C2 for each
given instance of C1, we use the assertion

[image]

I just cannot understand how the mandatory participation of C2 in the assertion is expressed by an assertion on C1, how is the last assertion read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *A* a as a property name is a bit unusual, so I'm going to use *p* instead.  The UML diagram doesn't express the *direction* of the property either, which makes the rest of the discussion a bit confused. Some information can be gleaned from the axioms you've provided, though.

If the UML is designed to express:

> 1. Instances of C<sub>1</sub> are related by *p* to at least n<sub>l</sub> and and most n<sub>u</sub> instances of C<sub>2</sub>.
> 2. At least m<sub>l</sub> and and most m<sub>u</sub> instances of C<sub>1</sub> are related by *p* to each instance of C<sub>2</sub>.

then you could use the DL axioms:

> C<sub>1</sub> ⊑ ≥n<sub>l</sub> p.C<sub>2</sub>
>   C<sub>1</sub> ⊑ ≤n<sub>u</sub> p.C<sub>2</sub>
>   C<sub>2</sub> ⊑ ≥m<sub>l</sub> p<sup>-1</sup>.C<sub>1</sub>
>   C<sub>2</sub> ⊑ ≥m<sub>u</sub> p<sup>-1</sup>.C<sub>1</sub>

Those say that *if* x is a C<sub>1</sub> (C<sub>2</sub>) then x is related to the appropriate number of C<sub>2</sub> (C<sub>1</sub>) instances by *p* (*p*<sup>-1</sup>).  Now, since the relationship as expressed in UML will only relate instances of the two classes, i.e., no other types of instances will be related by property *p*, then it's more likely that you would declare the domain and range of *p* as C<sub>1</sub> and C<sub>2</sub>, respectively, with:

> ∃p ⊑ C<sub>1</sub>
>   ∃p<sup>-1</sup> ⊑ C<sub>2</sub>

and then use a simpler version of the axioms above:

> C<sub>1</sub> ⊑ ≥n<sub>l</sub> p
>   C<sub>1</sub> ⊑ ≤n<sub>u</sub> p
>   C<sub>2</sub> ⊑ ≥m<sub>l</sub> p<sup>-1</sup>
>   C<sub>2</sub> ⊑ ≥m<sub>u</sub> p<sup>-1</sup>

To answer the very specific question:

> just cannot understand how the mandatory participation of C2 in the
>   assertion is expressed by an assertion on C1, how is the last
>   assertion read?

The notation in the last axiom in the question is unusual, and I'm not sure *exactly* what's supposed to be. I'm not sure what the little circumflexes are suppose to be.  It *looks* like:

> C<sub>1</sub> ⊑ ∃ p

though.  If that's what it is, it's read as

> C<sub>1</sub> is a subclass of ∃ p

which means that that

> If *x* is an instance of C<sub>1</sub> then *x* is an instance of ∃ p

which means that

> If *x* is an instance of C<sub>1</sub> then *x* is an instance of the class of things that have at least value for *p* (i.e., there is at least one *y* such that *p*(x,y)).

In first-order logic, you could express it as:

> ∀x.(C<sub>1</sub>(x) → ∃y.p(x,y))

Comment: Perfect. Your sentence "If x is an instance of C1 then x is an instance of the class of things that have at least value for p (i.e., there is at least one y such that p(x,y))." means that the minimum cardinality of y in the association is 1, which means that y is mandatory participating in P, and this is the purpose of the assertion made by the reference, as they say. Thanks :)

Comment: @MedianHilal The strange thing, though, is that they would use an existential (i.e., "at least one") restriction when the UML says "at least n" and OWL will let you say "at least n".  OWL will let you capture the UML better than what the paper shows.

Comment: Well, they use an "existential", for expressing "at least one" in UML, not "at least n". Here they discuss only the special cases (i.e. the 'one' multiplicity), while as you say the 'n' multiplicity case is easily expressible using OWL.